# MSSQL join row based on same number and order

Tags: php, sql, join

I am new at SQL Query. I have a question about how to join row in MSSQL when we have same number and order it by the order's number. Thanks

input :

```
No      order       Character
===     ======      ============
1       3           A     
1       2           B
1       1           C
2       3           D
2       2           E
2       1           F
```

Output :

```
No          Character
=========   ============
1           CBA   
2           FED
```

Comment: in MySQL you would use `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `group by`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum order than in SQL Server you can easily use conditional aggregation:

```
select no,
       ( max(case when [order] = 1 then character else '' end) +
         max(case when [order] = 2 then character else '' end) +
         max(case when [order] = 3 then character else '' end)
       )
from t
group by no;
```

If you don't, then you need the XML trick:

```
select no,
       (select character
        from t
        where t.no = n.no
        for xml path ('')
       ) as output 
from (select distinct no from t) n;
```

Comment: i used only 1 table but in your code there are 2 tables "t.no = n.no" table t and table n.

Comment: @rizal . . . `n` is an alias on the subquery, not a different table.

Comment: @rizal Should be 'path' not 'plath'